# No Error/Warning Can't Build Cordova Tools for Visual Studio 2013 Update 5

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am having strange issue in Cordova Tools for Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 Installation, there is no error/warning during the build process.

I have configured all the Environment Variables and the required Android Packages are all installed properly.

When I installed the Cordova Tools for Visual Studio I faced few Android SDK package errors and after installing them, now there is no error.

Here is the output of the build-

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  GeneratedJavascript=file.js;file.js.map;file.js;file.js.map
1>  C:\Users\Hardwell\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\FQVYKMBU.EB0\packages\vs-mda
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

All I am just trying a new blank project to build and run. Is there anything else which needs to be configured, I had followed these URLs to setup the things-

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn771551%28v=vs.120%29.aspx
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/

I have rechecked and confirmed that everything have been correctly installed and configured. Kindly help if someone has faced this same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily I found the answer myself, I had to clear the cache of the cordova tools for visual studio from the cordova options-

```
Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Cordova Tools > Clear Cordova Cache
```

After clearing cache and on next first build everything was properly configured again by Visual Studio and here is the build output-

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  GeneratedJavascript=file.js;file.js.map
1>  C:\Users\Hardwell\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\FQVYKMBU.EB0\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.76
1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
1>  npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is no longer maintained. See its readme for upgrade details.
1>  C:\Users\Hardwell\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-cli -> C:\Users\Hardwell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli.cmd
1>  vs-mda@0.1.76 C:\Users\Hardwell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda
1>  ├── ncp@0.5.1
1>  ├── q@1.0.1
1>  ├── rimraf@2.2.6
1>  ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>  ├── adm-zip@0.4.4
1>  ├── fstream@0.1.28 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.8)
1>  ├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
1>  ├── elementtree@0.1.6 (sax@0.3.5)
1>  ├── tar@0.1.20 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8)
1>  ├── request@2.36.0 (qs@0.6.6, mime@1.2.11, oauth-sign@0.3.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.1, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, node-uuid@1.4.7, tough-cookie@2.2.1, http-signature@0.10.1, hawk@1.0.0, form-data@0.1.4)
1>  ├── ripple-emulator@0.9.24 (colors@0.6.0-1, open@0.0.3, connect-xcors@0.5.2, accounting@0.4.1, request@2.12.0, moment@1.7.2, express@3.1.0)
1>  ├── plugman@0.22.4 (q@0.9.7, nopt@1.0.10, underscore@1.4.4, rc@0.3.0, cordova-lib@0.21.6, npm@1.3.4)
1>  └── cordova@4.3.1 (underscore@1.7.0, nopt@3.0.1, cordova-lib@4.3.1)
1>  ------ npm install of vs-mda@0.1.76 from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\FQVYKMBU.EB0\packages\vs-mda completed.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Hope it helps someone like me :)